# How to replace an ArcGIS elevation service with a GeoServer elevation service

Tags: geoserver, tiles, elevation

I'm trying to remove a dependency on ArcGIS in our system and I'm trying to replace ArcGIS's ImageServer with a counterpart on GeoServer.

Here's what I did so far:

1. Downloaded a sample elevation raster (GeoTIFF) from USGS.
2. Reprojected it to WGS 84 using QGIS.
3. Uploaded the projected raster as ImageMosaic to GeoServer.
4. Seeded a cached layer on gwc.

Here's what I'm getting in the tile preview:

[image: layer preview on geoserver]

The tile cache seems to be PNG pictures while I need a cache tile that is comprised of heights like ArcGIS's LERC format 
The height should be defined by this function:
`height = -10000 + ((R * 256 * 256 + G * 256 + B) * 0.1)`

How do I configure this information on GeoServer?
I've been searching everywhere and am looking for possible solutions.

To conclude here is what I need:

1. A LERC equivalent replacement.
2. If we're forced to use PNG, then configure it correctly and not just by creating a picture.
3. Serve the tiles by WMTS.
4. Tiles should calculate height information according to given function instead of a regular picture.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer** I have no idea how an ESRI Elevation Service works. So, I'm assuming that you want to have actual elevation values available in the client.

It sounds as if you need a [WCS](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wcs/reference.html) not a tile cache - a WMS will always serve a picture of your data, though I guess you could use [Jiffle](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#running-map-algebra-on-the-fly-using-jiffle) to calculate a LERC value but a WMS will still scale it to be an image.

Also if your GeoTiff has 3 bands (as it seems to need for the LERC formula you give) then it should display as an RGB image rather than grey scale as you show, so something odd is going on.

However, if my assumptions are wrong and you have a single band image with heights in it you may just need to look at adding a `<ColorMap>` to style your image to show different colours for different elevations. Then you could use a tilecache to speed display up. You should never just leave it with the default raster style as that will leave [discontinuities between your tiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308217/geotiff-rendered-in-openlayers-using-geoserver-tiles-have-different-brightness) (as in your screenshot).